# Is there a tool that will generate packet diagram from a data structure script?

Tags: windows, software-development, graphs

I'm looking for a Windows application that will generate packet diagrams from some simple data structure script. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716453/960757) on Stack Overflow and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197818/960757) (mentioning [dformat](https://github.com/sathlan/dformat) script) is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work in Windows (I found groff for Windows, but can't figure out how to get that preprocessing [dformat](https://github.com/sathlan/dformat) script into it, though it would great and would suffice actually).

Ideally, I'm looking for a single purpose free tool that will produce from some simple data structure script diagram like this:

[image]

Is there something like that for Windows? Or, as a bonus question, is there any way to use that tool with [dformat](https://github.com/sathlan/dformat) script on Windows platform?

Comment: Graphviz, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tlama, got bored of [the Delphi tag on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:960757%20delphi)?

I have marked this question as a favorite & will be watching it closely.   You say "generate from script", but I salivate at the thought of "generate from log", for instance from WireShark. Care to expand your question?

If you want to leave it "as-is", then `dformat` is simply an Awk script.

Gogole is your friend - https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=awk%20for%20windows

For instance, [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows) or [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), or why not recompile the source for Windows with this [recommended configuration](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/)?

However the new & still zealous moderators prefer that we have actually used a program which we recommend (I understand, trying to lay foundations for a good site), and I can put hand on heart and say that for years I have used the Awk in [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). It might be overkill, installing the whole Cygwin environment just for Awk, but you have a plethora of answers here. Take your choice & Thanks for `dfromat`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, I've tried GnuWin, was able to run groff, but had no success with that dformat script. I just don't know what to do with it. I've tried many ways following a few manuals but I think I just missed the whole concept of that application. I've spend with it almost whole day and for now I postponed it to "who knows when" :-) But dformat could be the best for me I think, because I'm looking exactly for this output from such simple script input.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer and maybe one day I'll get back to dformat. If someone would tell me just *"you need to rebuild that groff project, otherwise that script won't work"* would help me as well because I seriously don't know what I've been doing there. I thought just, oh great, a script, I'll just put into a directory where the binary finds it and run an example. Ehm, but the only output I got was the input script rendered on the image :-)

Comment: I want to see this working too. Do you have a sample input file, or a URL for one, which I can use to test as I play around?

Comment: An example script with its output is [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197818/960757).

Comment: Ok I am on to it.  Maybe an interesting little Delphi project if we can't get Awk to work? Add a few features & bung it on SourceFourge. Complete program? Or just a VCL component for others to incorporate?  Wag!  I lve th suggested "packetdiag - program for writing some more simple diagrams, with an online tool" at http://interactive.blockdiag.com/packetdiag/  Wuld a front-end be acceptable, or do you need offline capabilities? I am thinking that a GraphViz front-end might also be a solution  http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php